# How to format btrfs partition?

Tags: gparted, btrfs

How to format spare disk space to **btrfs** filesystem? I can't see btrfs in format dialog neither in gparted, nor in Disk Utility. Only Fat,ext2,ext3,ext4 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because [btrfs is not really stable yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4752/is-btrfs-in-maverick-considered-stable). So I guess the GUI tools do not support it yet, and you will have to use command line tools if you want to use it.

Comment: Now GParted does support BTRFS after installing btrfs-tools.

Answer (score 7):

You might need to install the package [btrfs-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/btrfs-tools) [image: Install btrfs-tools]. This should enable integration with gparted and etc.

Comment: It was already installed. Still no option for btrfs...

Comment: Odd. I will do some digging. Perhaps you might just need to use the command line tools. Just make a blank partition with something like cfdisk and then use mkfs.btrfs to create the filesystem.

Comment: Ubuntu's GParted seems to be missing btrfs support. This might be a bug and will definitely be fixed with GParted 0.7.0: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=571170

Comment: That probably should have been the answer htorque. :)

Comment: Yea, I confirm BTrFS support for everything but shrink and grow in Gparted 0.7.1.

Answer (score 2):

On newer versions of Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install btrfs-progs btrfs-compsize
```

Note: compsize is optional. It's needed to measure the compression (if enabled) of the btrfs filesystem.

More https://github.com/kilobyte/compsize