# JFS vs. EXT4 vs. EXT3

Tags: partitioning, ext4, ntfs, ext3, jfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to partition, and what is the best file-system for a new Hard Disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16642/what-is-the-best-way-to-partition-and-what-is-the-best-file-system-for-a-new-har)

I've got a 2TB external HD on which I save valuable data. so far I'm using NTFS as my file system, but I find it quite slow because I've got lots of files there. (700GB of videos, 20GB of music, etc.)

I want to encrypt some of the files (personal) and not the whole partition, and I would like the partition to run smoothly and not as laggy as now.

I read about JFS and EXT4 and EXT3 but each of them has got pros and cons. Can someone explain to me which one is the best for my needs?

Comment: Ext4 can now be read by ext2read (http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/) though ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before ext4 came out, I switched my mythtv backend to JFS for all of it's drives simply because JFS offered the best speed vs. CPU usage when dealing with files that were 1G of larger.  This was especially true when comparing delete speed with ext3.

The one area I have seen some question is dealing with lots and lots of files being open at the same time.  Supposedly JFS does not do as well in this scenario as some of the other options, but for my application (storing lots of video files, with very little concurrent access) this isn't an issue.

I have not compared things with ext4, since I don't really feel like rebuilding the machine at this point, so YMMV.

Of course, the disclaimers of "if it isn't NTFS, Windows won't read it" apply.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to be able to access the disk from Windows, then you need to stick with NTFS, otherwise go with ext4.

Comment: i just use ubuntu for now. but for the default file system in Ubuntu 10.10 i find out that it took quite slow to load all the file in the hard disk. i heard JFS is better and much stabil. and i read in some blog that EXT4 is just a temporary fix for EXT3.

Comment: thanks for the info. i saw ur post there for ext2 installer for window. so if i use that, is it possible for the windows virus to attack n corrupt existing data in my disk? FYI im dualbooting ubuntu and win7 now.

Comment: Ext4 is the preferred filesystem of Linux, and the default choice in Ubuntu.

Comment: @momoxxen : No, Ubuntu is indamagable to viruses.

Comment: @MichealH: But Windows's viruses may destroy data on ext partitions if the user is using a program to access Linux partions from Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have no issues with EXT4. It is what Ubuntu comes with as the default Journaling File System. It cannot be read on Windows, though.

As for JFS, It is a 64-bit File System. It will also not work On Windows, So If you are busy Dual-booting then NTFS will have to do.

They both have No Limits on Space (Well, Not for a while at 16 Petabytes for JFS and 16 Terabytes on EXT4) But It depends on user Preference :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd also like to add XFS to the mix.  I found it a bit more responsive especially with large files.  Ability to expand file system, and do a fs check without unmounting is pretty slick.

Though if you want to use Linux + Win, you're stuck on NTFS.